# Create a User for Select Only on Postgresql. Restrict "ALTER TABLE"

Tags: postgresql

I am using fallowing scripts for Create a user.

```
CREATE ROLE readonly LOGIN PASSWORD 'thePwd';

-- Existing objects

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE the_db TO readonly;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;

GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
```

After Create User & Role; the "readonly" user have "SELECT" permission. No Drop or Truncate rights. But "readonly" user have right "Alter Table" command.

How can I restrict for a specific user "Alter Table" rights?

Is there a simple example?

Comment: It shouldn't have, based on the commands shown.

Comment: Is there a sample script?

Comment: Did you CONNECT to the_db before the `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ...`  ?

Comment: Please show the command that works but shouldn't and the output of `\dp tablename` on the affected table

Comment: I used the above SQL Scripts,  Step by step. The readonly user working very well as expected by SELECT scripts ( no Drop, no Truncate ) ; expect for 'ALTER TABLE SAMPLE ADD/DROP Column "column_sample" '

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, I am doing it after connecting to the Database. Isn't it supposed to be like this? I am also facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

The solution is at the following script;

```
create user dummy_user with nosuperuser encrypted password 'dummy_password';

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE the_db TO dummy_user;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO dummy_user;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dummy_user;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO dummy_user;

GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO dummy_user;
```

Comment: I am still facing issue after this :( Able to run alter command still.